# How to list all local computer user profiles in a combo box?

Tags: c#

I need to enumerate all user profiles on a local computer and list them in a combo box. Any special accounts need to be filtered out. I'm only concerned about actual user profiles on the computer where the app is running. I have done some searching but I haven't found a clear answer posted anywhere. I did find some code that might work but SelectQuery and ManagementObjectSearcher are displaying errors in VS and I'm not sure what I need to do to make this work.

```
using System.Management;

SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
{
     Console.WriteLine("Username : {0}", envVar["Name"]);
}
```

Comment: [SelectQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.selectquery.aspx) and [ManagementObjectSearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx) are documented (including the `namespace` where they live) in the links I just provided.

Comment: You need to add a reference (and optionally, a `using` statement) to `System.Management`?

Comment: I do have using System.Management in my application. I forgot to include it here.

Comment: Two separate things - 1) Add a reference, 2) Add a `using`. They're different things.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a reference. When I added "using System.Object", it cleared 4 errors I was seeing but now I have a new one. "A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Object' is a type, not a namespace".

Comment: After adding System.Management as a reference and changing the console.writeline command to messagebox.show, I can see there are many names produced. None of the names were profiles on my computer except for maybe some special profiles. Where does the list of names come from using my code snippet above? Based on the names that I was seeing, I was beginning to think they were being pulled from AD. From what I have seen so far, the code snippet above is not going to work in my situation. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

By saying "SelectQuery and ManagementObjectSearcher are displaying errors" I guess you didn't reference the `System.Management` dll.
You should right click **References** in your solution and add **System.Management**.
Then, with your `using` statement, the errors should disappear.

Anyway, including the error next time will assist everyone to help you :)

Comment: Ok, I added a reference for System.Management and all of the errors have cleared up. I will play with the code snippet I posted above to see if it produces the results that I'm looking for. How can I determine when a Reference is needed rather than a "using" statement alone?

Comment: When the compiler can't find a type or a namespace, it gives the following error: `The type or namespace name 'X' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`  
You can see all the dlls referenced in your solution under **References**. If you don't have the required dll there, you need to add it. If it's already there, you can add an `using` statement to avoid typing the full namespace before each type, for example: `System.Management.SelectQuery`.

Comment: About your second question, I tried this code on my machine and it works pretty well. You could try this [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/06/03/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-list-all-the-user-profiles-on-a-computer.aspx) but it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: I think what I really need is a list of profiles found at C:\Users. I am developing a custom GUI front-end for USMT 5.0. The user should pick the profile in C:\Users that they want to backup. When I ran the snippet above, it pulled up many usernames but the only profile on my computer is my own. I know some of them were special accounts but I was expecting it to produce my profile, administrator, maybe public and the special profiles. I saw usernames that I know for sure have never logged into my computer.

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned code is great but when I tried on a machine connected to a Active Directory Domain all the usernames where returned for the domain.  I was able to tweak the code a bit to only return the users that actually have a local directory on the current machine. If a better C# developer can refactor the code to make it cleaner - please help!

```
var localDrives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
var localUsers = new List<string>();
var query = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount") { Condition = "SIDType = 1 AND AccountType = 512" };
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

foreach (ManagementObject envVar in searcher.Get())
{
    foreach (string drive in localDrives)
    {
        var dir = Path.Combine(String.Format("{0}Users", drive), envVar["name"].ToString());
        if (Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            localUsers.Add(envVar["name"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have the localUsers variable you can set this as the data source to your ComboBox control of our choice.